How can I seal the joint between my wall tile and bathroom countertop?
The grout on the tile behind the bathroom sink is missing a bit along the corner, as shown in the attached picture. I'd like to fill this space as it's an easy place for water to be when someone is using the sink. Should I be using grout here or should I be using a sanded caulk product? I'm seeing very different recommendations for this type of thing online. Preferably I'd like to be able to fix it without having to remove the sink handles, but will do whatever needs to be done to get it done right.


Do you have any idea whether it was there once and has gone, or if it was badly done in the first place? From the cracking in the grout line below the leftmost tile I reckon it's come out, and you need something more flexible

The picture makes it seem like there is only a tiny space to work in with the taps and faucet in place.  You will want a couple of inches at least to do decent work behind them.  Removing/cleaning the old/loose grout will take space also.

@ChrisH, I don't have a strong view on that. This is a new house. My guess is that it was once there and has gone, but I'm not at all sure about that.

You wouldn't use grout, as there's likely movement in the counter top. You also wouldn't use sanded grout, as that's not what you have. (Sanded grout is rarely used with joints that narrow or with glossy tile as it can scratch on application.)
Use a quality tub & tile caulk. If there's nowhere you need it painted, pure silicone should work well. Otherwise get a paintable caulk, possibly with silicone.
Clean the joint as well as you can with alcohol before applying and use a small bead (cut the nozzle very small and at a slight angle). It should look like the grout joints if you do it well, not like a big cove of goop. One strategy is to mask the tile and countertop to limit contact, then cove the bead before unmasking with a wet finger or other tool.

That should be caulked, not grouted.  I would use a tool (pick, scraper, oscillating multitool, etc.) to chip out the grout, then replace with silicone caulk.  If the faucet and handles can be removed to do the work, that would be ideal, otherwise you'll have to figure some workaround (like maybe taping a caulk line and just slathering it on before you scrape it off).

Removing faucet handles should be easy; I've replaced faucets several times and can't recall ever having trouble removing them. (The only likely serious trouble is if your water shutoffs don't work... which would be something you should fix regardless.) The "hardest" part is cleaning them off for application of fresh putty when reinstalling.
